# On the relation between eulerian graph and eulerian hypergraph?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path, hypergraphs

**Definition**
The 2-section  of a hypergraph $H$, denoted by $[H]_2$, is the graph with the same vertices of the hypergraph, and edges between all pairs of vertices contained in the same hyperedge.

A hypergraph is called eulerian if it admits an euler tour  which visits every hyperedge exactly once (Note that euler tour of a hypergraph  starts and ends in the same hyperedge but maybe in two different  vertices -of the same hyperedge-).

**Example**
The euler tour of  the first  hypergraph is $\{E_4, E_1,E_2,E_3,E_5,E_4\}$. Note that the euler tour in this case could begin in vertex $v_2$ and ends in vertex $v_3$ (that is euler tour in hypergraph my starts and ends in different vertices -unlike the graph case-).

The   2-section of a hypergraph is illustrated in the second figure

[image]
[image]

**Question** 
My question is if the 2-section graph of the hypergraph  $[H]_2$ is eulerian, does this implies that the hypergraph $H$ is also eulerian ?

**Comment** 
I'm pretty sure that the above question has positive answer (at least for the case of $k$-uniform hypergraph that is all the hyperedges have the same size $k$), but I do not have any idea how to start!

Any idea  will be useful!

Comment: It appears that this question is somewhat answered in this paper: http://shyam.nitk.ac.in/es-papers/ES070%20Eulerian%20Hypergraphs.pdf in propositions 3 and 4. They state that if the hypergraph is Eulerian, so is $[H]_2$, but not necessarily the reverse (at least that's what I gathered from looking at it for a few minutes).

Comment: @Bob1123 If $H$ is eulerian then $[H]_2$ could be not eulerian, for instance the 2-section of the first hypergraph in the above question is not eulerian since the degree of vertex $v_3$ is odd (in $[H]_2$).

Comment: They might be counting multiple edges for $v_3$ and $v_8$ since they are both in two of the same edges. I'm not sure without reading more into it though...

Comment: @Bob1123 Thank you ! In fact, the paper that you gave gives deep insight to the question.